# Use psycopg2 executemany to improve the query

Tags: python, postgresql

I have the below query using execute to add data using execute, what would be a executemany version of this code?

```
import psycopg2
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()


urlstocopy = return_list_urls2(1300000)



def main():
# fake values

    conn_string = "host='db-etherator-do-user--0.b.db.oean.com' port='60' dbname='etherr2' user='in' password='sadf'"
    conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    # convert them into list of tuples
    x = 1
    for link in urlstocopy:
        values = (x, '', '', '', '', link, '2022-10-10', '2022-10-10')
        sql = f'''insert into accounts_website(id, business_name, industry, trade, acc_notes,website,created_on,updated) values{str(values)}'''
        cursor.execute(sql)
        conn.commit()
        print(x)
        x = x+1
    conn.close()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: As stated in [the documentation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html?highlight=executemany#cursor.executemany), if performance is what you have in mind, then you are better off using `execute` in a loop

Comment: 1) Read [Parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) on the correct and safe procedures to pass in parameters. 2) Use from here [Fast execution helpers](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries)  `execute_batch` or `execute_values`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code already has a problem, because you're not handling quoting.  If there are quote characters in your URLs, your query will explode.  You need this:

```
    rows = []
    for x,link in enumerate(urlstocopy):
        rows.append( (x+1, '', '', '', '', link, '2022-10-10', '2022-10-10') )

    sql = 'insert into accounts_website(id, business_name, industry, trade, acc_notes,website,created_on,updated) values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);'
    cursor.executemany(sql, rows)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: After trying this I am getting the error TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting ‍♂️

Comment: That is because the code is incorrect, the number(7) of placeholders `%s` does not match the number(8) of values being passed in. Also `for x,link in enumerate(urlstocopy):` can be changed to `for x,link in enumerate(urlstocopy, 1):` to get 1 based indexing and avoid the `x + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Fast execution helpers](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries)

```
create table so_test(id integer, varchar_fld varchar, bool_fld boolean);

import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import execute_batch, execute_values

con = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test user=postgres host=localhost port=5432")
cur = con.cursor()


rows = [[1, 'test', 't'], [2, 'dog', 'f'], [3, 'cat', 't']]
execute_batch(cur, 'insert into so_test(id, varchar_fld, bool_fld)  values (%s, %s, %s)', rows)

rows = [[4, 'test', 't'], [5, 'dog', 'f'], [6, 'cat', 't']]
execute_values(cur, 'insert into so_test(id, varchar_fld, bool_fld)  values %s', rows)

con.commit()

select * from so_test ;
 id | varchar_fld | bool_fld 
----+-------------+----------
  1 | test        | t
  2 | dog         | f
  3 | cat         | t
  4 | test        | t
  5 | dog         | f
  6 | cat         | t
```

From the fast execution helpers link:

> The current implementation of executemany() is (using an extremely charitable understatement) not particularly performing. These functions can be used to speed up the repeated execution of a statement against a set of parameters. By reducing the number of server roundtrips the performance can be orders of magnitude better than using executemany().

Where "These functions ..." are `execute_batch` and `execute_values`. If you are going to deal with datasets of any size they are the way to go.